# How to automate rails project "bootstrap" consolidating routine customizations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As we create more Rails applications, I find myself routinely adjusting the project generated by `rails new ...` in exactly the same ways: adding rspec, capybara + capybara-webkit support, adjusting config/application.rb to our tastes, including several gems we came to love.

I had a look at [suspenders](https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders), it's a good starting point, but some of their choices differ from ours. Plus it's flexible in places where we don't really want any choice. In fact we'd rather have a couple project boilerplates sharing some customizations and each adding some unique extra's.

What are the options for streamlining/automating a project "bootstrap"? How could we organize a set of boilerplates and let them evolve as our preferences change (not adding options, but changing which made choices are hardcoded)?

I'm thinking in the direction of scripting what I normally do manually starting from `rails new`, editing the Gemfile, config/application.rb etc, but may be there is a cleaner (future versions compatible) approach or tool?

Comment: Someone has compiled a list of options here: http://railsapps.github.io/rails-application-templates.html

Comment: I'm wondering if [this](http://appscrolls.org/) might be of help to you

Comment: thanks, I'll check both resources out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like using the [Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-composer/) gem/tool for this.

At the basic level when you run Rails Composer it will ask you a series of questions about what gems/configuration options you'd like your new Rails app to have. Then generates your app for you.

I like the "ask me for what I want" approach because different Rails projects may need different things: Postgres vs MySQL, Bootstrap vs Zurb Foundation, etc. 90% of these are usually the same, but it's the 10% difference that gets me.

At the more advanced level, Rails Composer shows you how to use Rails templates to create your own standard modifications, or you could fork Rails Composer to add the options you want (maybe sending a PR back to the project if it's something useful?)

At the expert level, Rails Composer has "starter apps": just pick one of those and go, choices already made for you. Depending on your needs this might be just the kind of thing you're looking for -- digging into how these "starter" apps are created and making one yourself.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Flexibility is great, but I really want some of those questions have default answers, set by me. I probably need to have a closer look at Rails Composer - I bet there is a way.